# How can I let StringPosition consolidate overlapping matches?

Tags: pattern-matching, regular-expressions

Consider an example like this one:

```
StringPosition["  -aa.ef  -ag.hi   -aa.ei", 
 RegularExpression["\\s+-(?=a+\\.)"]]
```

which returns

```
{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {17, 20}, {18, 20}, {19, 20}}
```

because `\\s+` matches one or more space characters.

There are two matches for the first finding and three for the second one (the second sequence of white spaces is excluded because of the positive lookahead).

**How can I consolidate the overlapping matches to the largest one?**

Comment: You need to specify what comes before the pattern. For example, a negative look-behind with a space? Or a word boundary?

Comment: You might find it easier to use `StringSplit` repeatedly

Comment: Roman, do you mean something like the part ```(^|\\S)``` in ```StringPosition["  -aa.ef  -ag.hi   -aa.ei", RegularExpression["(^|\\S)\\s+-(?=a+\\.)"]]```? But this catches the non-white character before the ```\\t``` too, as you can see like this: ```StringReplacePart[#, "___", StringPosition[#, RegularExpression["(^|\\S)\\s+-(?=a+\\.)"]]]& @ "  -aa.ef  -ag.hi   -aa.ei"```: the lower case i is also replaced on each find.

Answer (score 3):

```
StringPosition["  -aa.ef  -ag.hi   -aa.ei", 
 RegularExpression["\\s+-(?=a+\\.)"], Overlaps-> False]

(*  {{1, 3}, {17, 20}}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

with a negative look-behind:

```
StringPosition["  -aa.ef  -ag.hi   -aa.ei",
  RegularExpression["(?<!\\s)\\s+-(?=a+\\.)"]]

(*    {{1, 3}, {17, 20}}    *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Roman's hint:

In my example prepending the search pattern with the *positive* (because of `=` instead of `!`) *lookbehind*:

`(?<=^|\\S)`

would do the trick in:

`StringPosition["  -aa.ef  -ag.hi   -aa.ei", RegularExpression["(?<=^|\\S)\\s+-(?=a+\\.)"]]`

It requires a begin of line or a non-white character to the left of the spaces to be caught together with the minus sign, a so called *lookbehind* condition (caution: the thing is called *lookbehind* although the requirement has to be true *before* the search pattern which follows matches but the match inside the *lookaround* is not caught. **Being surrounded by lookaround-conditions on both sides makes the match unique.**

**Note:** The inventors of regular expressions should have better called them **condition left of match** and **condition right of match**, instead of *lookbehind* and *lookahead*!